# How to access internet from CentOS 7 in my local network

Tags: linux, windows, networking, windows-10, centos-7

I have to make a local network for my CFD simulation as shown in the figure below.

The problem is how to access the internet from the CentOS 7 machine through the Win10 machine. 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Since you get access to the Internet through your Windows 10 PC, you can do the economy of the switch, and use ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) in Windows 10 instead. In Windows, go to Control Panel, Internet and Sharing, click on your wireless connection in the right-pane, choose Properties, then Sharing, and share your connection with your Ethernet port on the Windows 10 PC. Connect the other end of the cable to your CentOS machine, and voilà.

Comment: Thanks, I have enalbed the sharing now. you mean put the line direct into the win10 pc? we don't need the switch?

Comment: Not if your connection schematics looks like this: ISP > Router > PC Windows (via WiFi) > ICS (Windows's Internet Connection Sharing) > Ethernet > CentOS. Problem is, you'll have to leave your Windows PC running all the time (but that would be the case anyway, even with the switch in place) if you want CentOS to have Internet access. Try it and see if that works for you.